# How to represent a big number in Java

Tags: java

How can I represent and use a large number in Java? In scientific computing there are a number of times that I need numbers to be greater than a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for this..

They can be as large as you need - until you run out of memory.

**eg:**

```
BigInteger Bigintvar1 = new BigInteger("1234567890123456890");
BigInteger Bigintvar2 = new BigInteger("2743561234");
Bigintvar1 = Bigintvar1.add(Bigintvar2);
```

Comment: I have tried it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `java.math.BigInteger` class provides operations analogues to all of Java's primitive integer operators and for all relevant methods from `java.lang.Math`.

You can refer [here](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/data/numbers/10biginteger.html) for `BigInteger`